# .NET Core 1.1 MVC Controller method not getting called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a .NET Core 1.1 MVC controller that somehow isn't getting called correctly when a request comes in.

The controller method looks like this:
[image: Controller Method Signature]

Although I don't know if that really matters, because I have debugging lines in the controller's constructor (and have run in debug with breakpoints in the constructor, as well), and it looks like even the constructor is never getting called.

The application output contains a line like this, when the call comes into the server:

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action Namespace.NameController.GetData (AssemblyName) in 0.9161ms**

Something that is suspicious there is that most of the lines I see logged like this for other controllers being called contain the argument information, as well, and this one doesn't.

I'm not getting an error from the client side, instead I'm getting a success response with an empty body. It's almost like an empty response is getting returned before any of my controller's code actually runs.

Here are the details of the request/response (the response body is empty):

```
Request URL: http://localhost:61410/path-to-controller/GetData?xtype=xtypeargument
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
Query Url
xtype: xtypeargument
Request Headers
accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:61410
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Authorization: bearer <bearer-token>
Referer: http://localhost:61410/path-to/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Response Headers
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?...?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 06 Sep 2017 14:08:10 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Any ideas of what might be going on here?

Comment: 200 response, so it is getting into your application.  I would start adding logging to your controller if you can't stop on a break point, then removing method attributes to see if they are interfering.  Verify the controller path and that it is the expected controller as well.

Comment: So, the Namespace, class name and assembly name being logged at all correct. I have added logging to my controller and as far as I can tell the constructor is never even being called.

Comment: How are your routes set up? Is it possible that another endpoint is hit?  WebAPi always returns a 404 when a request does not end up in a method.  Maybe try to set a breakpoint on multiple methods/controllers

Comment: I've been trying multiple things, including setting breakpoints in base classes and in middleware. The thing that has me most confused is that the ControllerActionInvoker log has the correct class/method.

Comment: Another thing I've tried is removing the controller class altogether. When I do that, I get a 404, as I would expect.

Comment: Alright...I've commented everything else from the controller except the method being called and have that returning null. Now my debug break point gets hit in there. Will start removing comments and see what breaks it.

Comment: It seems that as soon as I add in the constructor that uses DI, the controller stops working properly. Maybe it's taking a type that isn't correctly set up for DI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the controller's constructor had arguments that were expected to be provided by Dependency Injection, but that weren't. Somehow this caused the behavior I was seeing, although I still don't really understand why I wasn't getting exceptions instead of these empty responses. Anyway, I fixed the code and it's working now.